# How to convert a PHP DateTime object to ISO string?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date that I receive in MS format for JSON dates.  It looks like this:

```
/Date(1365004652303)/
```

I can convert it to a PHP DateTime object by doing this:

```
$timestamp = round(((int) $originalMSdate) / 1000);
$convertedDate = new DateTime();
$convertedDate->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

Ultimately, though, I need it to be a string in ISO 8601 format.  I tried then converting it to an ISO date object & then converting that to a string with strval() but strval() doesn't work on date objects.

I've also tried

```
$dateString = date_format($convertedDate, 'YY-MM-DD H:i:s');
```

but I need it to also include timezone info, like this: 2015-10-01T21:22:57.057Z
I don't see characters for that in date_format.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm not printing the resulting string.  I need to pass it to a field in a database that accepts a string datatype.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Format code `c` for ISO 8601; as per [PHP Documentation](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: ... or `DateTime::ATOM` : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Ah, thank you, @Mark Baker.  I didn't see 'c' because i was looking at Date object formatting, rather than date string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```
<?php
// input
$time = microtime(true);
// Determining the microsecond fraction
$microSeconds = sprintf("%06d", ($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
// Creating DT object
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'. $microSeconds, $time), $tz);
$iso8601Date = sprintf(
    "%s%03d%s",
    $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s."),
    floor($dt->format("u")/1000),
    $dt->format("O")
);
// Formatting according to ISO 8601-extended
var_dump(
     $iso8601Date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$timestamp = round(((int) $originalMSdate) / 1000);
$dateString = date('c', $timestamp);
```

The format isn't EXACTLY the same.  It's in this format:

2016-04-25T14:27:00-05:00 rather than 
2016-04-25T14:27:00.057Z

but it's close enough that I can do some manipulation to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

this one is worked for me. For more please [refer](https://devland.at/a/iso-8601-dates-in-php-and-browsers) this article.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

echo date('c', strtotime($date));                // 2020-04-08T16:04:56+05:30
echo date(DateTime::ISO8601, strtotime($date));  // 2020-04-08T16:04:56+0530
echo date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime($date));     // 2020-04-08T16:04:56+05:30
```